# Looping after secting type

Tags: mysql, powershell

I have ran into an issue when i run the second part of this code it loops and constantly asks to set location you want to run staging. I can select between the TC, MonsterLock, and Cyc but once i enter the second part no matter what I enter it still asks me the same thing.

the loop i am getting looks like this

This script sets up DATABASE Staging
Sets up location you want to run staging
you have enterd an error -ForgroundColor Red
You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL
you typed DATABASE1
set location you want to run staging
you have enterd an error -ForgroundColor Red
You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL
you typed DATABASE2
set location you want to run staging
you have enterd an error -ForgroundColor Red
You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL
you typed DATABASE3
set location you want to run staging

```
write-host "This script sets up DATABASE Staging"
$ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(TC/MonsterLock/Cyc)"
While($ProductionDistro -notmatch "(TC|MonsterLock|Cyc)"){
    write-host "You have entered an error" -ForegroundColor Red
    write-host "You must type TC or MonsterLock or Cyc"
    write-host "you typed $ProductionDistro"
    write-host "This script sets up DATABASE Staging"
    $ProductionDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which production do you `enter code here`want to run?(TC/MonsterLock/Cyc)"
}

write-host "Sets up location you want to run staging"
        $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
        While($ElementDitro -notmatch "(DATABASE1|DATABASE2|DATABASE3|DATABASE4|ALL)") {
            write-host "you have enterd an error" -ForgroundColor Red
            write-host "You must type DATABASE1 or DATABASE2 or DATABASE3 or DATABASE4 or ALL"
            write-host "you typed $ElementDistro"
            write-host "set location you want to run staging"
          $ElementDistro = Read-Host -Prompt "Which Element do you want to run? (DATABASE1/DATABASE2/DATABASE3/DATABASE4/ALL)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo. While(**$ElementDitro** is missing an **s** in it.

Also, -Foreground should have an e in it. That may have been my fault, I think I fat fingered that in my previous answer to your other question.

Comment: that fixed the loop I had with it. I will let you know if anything else pops up and I can't figure out how to rewrite it.